# Relationship between forward and backward map in Isomorphism (Lens package)

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Why does/Should nothing constrain `s` to be isomorphic to `t`, and `b` to be isomorphic to `a` in an Isomorphism of type `Iso s t a b`?

I understand we have a forward mapping `s -> a`, and a backward mapping `b -> t`, but why is there no relationship imposed on these mappings in

```
 type Iso s t a b = forall p f. (Profunctor p, Functor f) => p a (f b) -> p s (f t)
```

Comment: See http://comonad.com/reader/2012/mirrored-lenses/ section "Why is it a lens family?"

Comment: @bennofs That link helped me understand this better, so I have incorporated some into my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you would want to be isomorphic is not `s` to `t` or `a` to `b`, but instead `s` to `a` and `t` to `b`. Consider the example:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> (True, ()) & swapped . _1 %~ show
(True,"()")
```

Here, we are composing the `Iso` `swapped` with the `Lens` `_1`; in this use their composition is equivalent to the `Lens` `_2`, and so `show` gets applied to the second element of the tuple `(True, ())`. Note that `show` is type-changing. So what type are we actually using the `Iso` `swapped` at here?

- `s` is the type of our original tuple, `(Bool, ())`
- `t` is the type of the final result, `(Bool, String)`
- `a` is the type of `s` after swapping, `((), Bool)`
- `b` is the type of `t` before swapping back, `(String, Bool)`

In other words, we are using `swapped` at the type

```
swapped :: Iso (Bool, ()) (Bool, String) ((), Bool) (String, Bool)
```

Each of the mappings `s -> a` and `b -> t` is a bijection, but there is no such necessary relationship between the other types.

As for why there seem to be no listed laws for `Iso`s that say that these need to be bijections, I do not know.

EDIT: The section "Why is it a lens family" in the link posted by @bennofs in the comments above really clarified some things for me. Clearly Edward Kmett does *not* intend these types to vary completely freely.

Although it cannot be expressed *directly* in the types of an optic without making it awkward to use,
the intention is that a type-changing optic family (`Lens`, `Iso` or other) should have types given by type families `inner` and `outer`.  If one of the types of an `Iso` is

```
anIso :: Iso s t a b
```

Then there should be two index types `i` and `j` such that

```
s = outer i
t = outer j
a = inner i
b = inner j
```

Moreover, you are permitted to swap `i` and `j`, and although there is no automatic enforcement of this, the result *should* still be a legal type for your polymorphic `Iso`. I.e. you should also be allowed to use `anIso` at the type

```
anIso :: Iso t s b a
```

Clearly this holds for `swapped`. Both of these are legal types for it:

```
swapped :: Iso (Bool, ()) (Bool, String) ((), Bool) (String, Bool)
swapped :: Iso (Bool, String) (Bool, ()) (String, Bool) ((), Bool)
```

In other words, if a polymorphic `Iso` family is type changing, then it is also required to support the *reverse* type change. (Also composed type changes. I smell a natural transformation from category theory here, which I suspect is also a way Kmett thinks of this.)

Note also that if you have a polymorphic `Iso` constructed as

```
f :: s -> a
g :: b -> t
iso f g :: Iso s t a b
```

Then in order for this *also* to have the type `iso f g :: Iso t s a b`, we need `f` and `g` to also have the types

```
f :: t -> b
g :: a -> s
```

Note that `f` used at its first type `s -> a` has the right type to be the inverse of `g` used at its second type `a -> s`, and correspondingly the other way.

For a concrete example, `swapped` is a little bad here since its `f` and `g` as used for tuples are identical, essentially they are both `\(x,y) -> (y,x)`, which is its own inverse. And the best other non-`Simple` example I see in `Control.Lens.Iso` is `curried`, which seems a little too complicated to be clarifying.

Comment: What is the need for two unrelated bijections? Also how do we get a reverse mapping for these bijections?

Comment: @user3585010 In practice they won't be *completely* unrelated, naturally. As far as I know there is no way to reverse the mappings just from the information in the `Iso`. To reverse the `Iso` you just switch the two mappings, so `Iso s t a b` becomes `Iso b a t s`. However in the special case of `Iso' s a` the mappings are supposed to be each other's inverses, I think this follows from requiring the `Iso'` and its reverse to follow the `Lens` laws. Come to think of it, the lens laws really only make sense for simple lenses too.

Comment: Looking at the documentation though, the iso function is supposed to construct an isomorphism from 'a pair of inverse functions' the type of which is Iso s t a b.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen That's what `from` does.

Comment: @user3585010 That link bennofs posted really clarified some stuff for me, so I have added to my post.

Comment: @DavidYoung I know. I think my comment may have been confusing because I was trying to distinguish reversing the `Iso` from reversing each of the mappings it is constructed from.